Why does multi level page table save memory compared to linear page table?
I'm studying operating system now and come across this concept here.
page table
explanation
It's mentioned that for a linear page table on the left, even if a page is invalid it will still use page table space so 16 pages will be used anyway. For a multi-level page table on the right however, only 3 page table will be used.
My question is why are there only three pages used on the right? Wouldn't there still be 4 entries for each page table/directory so 4x3 = 12 should be used?
Moreover, on the left a page will still be in use even if it's marked invalid. But on the right in the page directory, why are the two directories in the middle not used when they are marked invalid?
I'm new to operating systems so I'm confused of the concepts. Thanks to everyone that could help!
